# Closing Application and killing it from ram

Tags: android

hi I want to close my application and also want kill it from ram by clicking button.
i am using this method, but it just minimize application and didn't
close complete app. what to do ?

```
public void AppExit()
{

    this.finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: call `System.exit(0);`

Comment: thanks dear and so nice of you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling:

- `System.exit(0);`
- `Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Both of which are **definitely** not a *good idea*!

Instead use the activity's `finish();` method - let Android handle the cleanup of RAM management, which it is very good in doing so!

If you do not want your activity to be shown in the activity stack, the flags, 
`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` would usually suffice for launching another activity.

***OR*** specify in your `AndroidManifest.xml` in your activity tag, `android:noHistory="true"`.

Comment: +1 for the useful flags. As a side note, `finish()` does not do the same thing as `System.exit` or `Process.killProcess`. It only flags current Activity as no longer used. This doesn't mean the app is going to shutdown, specially if there are other Activities running.

Answer (score 1):

`System.exit` will exit the VM and Android will kill this process.

`Activity#finish()` is usually the popular choice, but this does not need to be executed right away and also only affects this particular Activity, not the whole process.

Just FYI: killing apps manually is not a good app design in Android (except maybe some special situations). If you could explain why you want to kill your app, we can probably tell you a better solution.

Comment: i simply want to close my app.
i don't want it to remain in back and being shown in task manager.

Comment: Why not? This doesn't sound like a wise design for a normal Android app. This will only make the user not wanting to use your app.

Answer (score 0):

use single line code

```
System.exit(1);
```

or

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: Why 1 on `exit`? This in Linux indicates the process ended with an error.