# Android: Simulate the back button twice

Tags: android

I have a situation where I have a three step registration process. Each step is contained in its own activity - call them A, B, and C. Only when I get to the end of step three, can I reliably validate one of the inputs (and email address to which I send a confirmation using PHPMailer). If this comes back with an error, I want to go all the way back to A, which is where the email address is entered.

This is easy enough by just calling an Intent. However, I want to retain the input values that the user entered originally so that they don't have to enter them again. Theoretically, the easiest way to do this is to call `finish()` twice. But this doesn't work since calling it once transfers control back to B and the second call never happens.

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I have to call Intent and then somehow populate the fields through another method? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229797/closing-application-and-killing-it-from-ram/18229915#18229915) - *hint* the clue is in the flags....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely get you but you could use the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to bring it back to A and remove B.

```
Intent i = new Intent(C.this, A.class)
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Run this code when you get the error and it will bring A back up. And if the "Back" button is pressed you will still get to B.

Another option you have is to store the information in something like [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and load the data from there but this may be unnecessary for your situation.

Comment: This seems like it should work. However, when I get back to A, all of my fields are cleared, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. One change to your code that I had to make was to the second line, which I had to make `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to avoid the error `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP cannot be resolved to a variable`. Do you agree with this change or should I handle it differently? Thanks!

Comment: No, that is correct. Sorry, I don't usually forget that. I will edit my answer

Comment: Then store them in `SharedPreferences` as I suggested and reload the data frome there

Answer (score -1):

To pass data around between activities, use a `Bundle`, for an example, in this class activity - `B`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putBoolean("some_boolean_value", true);
b.putInt("some_int_value", 4);
b.putString("some_string_value", "foobar");
intent.putExtra("fooBundle", b);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Then, from your class activity 'C', after it appears on screen, from within the `onCreate` method, extract the bundle:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("fooBundle")){
        Bundle b = savedInstanceState.getBundle("fooBundle");
        int nVal = b.getInt("some_int_value");
        String sVal = b.getString("some_string_value");
        boolean blnVal = b.getBoolean("some_boolean_value");
        // Do whatever you have to do, put them into textview's etc.
    }
}
```

Notice, how the check is made to ensure *there* is indeed a bundle, if not, its an "*empty view*" i.e. no data to prefill into the fields. And reverse the pulling out the values from the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).

When you back out of the class activity `C`, it goes back to activity `A`.

## Edit

The OP is insistent on using "two" back key strokes which is deemed unnecessary as the flag indicating the activity is cleared from the stack.

> A -> B

*Before creating the intent in the above code and runs, the stack now becomes...*

> A -> C

Now back out of the activity `C`, by pressing the back key.

> A

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know that I can do it that way (or using shared preferences). Just seeing if there is a quick way to simulate two 'back' clicks. I may very well wind up doing it like this, though. Thanks!

Comment: Shared preferences are not the way to go in doing something like this.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. The question wasn't about how to pass data around but how to get back to A with an error and remove B. With this code, if the user presses back on C then they will be taken to A but that's not what they want

Comment: Thanks for this post. However, after implementing it, it still doesn't work. I get an empty screen A, exactly what I am trying to avoid. Also, I have to code around a null pointer error with the savedInstanceState bundle on the initial entry into A.

Comment: @codeMagic The OP asked this which is what I thought was also part of the question *Is there a simple way to do this, or do I have to call Intent and then **somehow populate the fields through another method** ? Thanks!*

Comment: Ahhhhh! Gotcha, I misinterpreted as passing data through A->B->C - not the other way around which is what the OP is looking for? In that case, use `this.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);` from activity A, when finished in activity C, pass the bundle back in with the `requestCode` as dictated by the parameter.

Comment: I see. What is wrong with `SharedPreferences` in this situation? To retain the data when going back to A after an authentication error, I mean. I agree it is unnecessary just to send the data to B and C but this would save it in case of an error. And it would be there later if necessary

Comment: It not always going back to A...only when there is an authentication error and the user has to go back to A to input the correct information.

Comment: Would this [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)

Comment: To clarify: The activities build chronologically from A->B->C. After validating in C, there is an error situation where I want to go all the way back to A. I'd like to have the fields in A be populated with the user's original entries so that they don't have to re-input everything.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, in that case, why not save the data in the bundle in the `onSaveInstanceState`, that is in activity A, launch the intent to activity B, then launch the activity C, if that fails, the activity C is popped off stack back to Activity A, the `onRestoreInstanceState` will be fired and the values are there?

Comment: SharedPreferences are limited - rather more for application preferences, not for passing data around. You can store arrays, objects etc in a bundle and is more optimized as it gets serialized into what is essentially a `Parcelable` and faster retrieval over xml.