# How to exit from application permanently in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am doing one application here I have one exit button when I click button,that time I need to exit from application..I tried using below code app is closing but it still running in taslmanager..but when I click exit button I should close app as well as I should remove from task manager how it's possible.

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
    Button exit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

        exit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

      startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
   }
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing Application and killing it from ram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229797/closing-application-and-killing-it-from-ram)

Comment: also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238276/android-simulate-the-back-button-twice#comment26739948_18238276)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Answer (score 0):

Use this flag:

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`.

This flag will notify the OS to remove this `app/activity` from the cache of recent apps.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

You can also add

```
android:noHistory="true"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

in your `AndroidManifest` file for the activity where you don't want to see in recent apps.

Comment: tahnkyou..i gave that falg also but still app is there in taskmanager

Comment: you should use this flag with the `cleartop` flag you have in your code. Don't remove that flag either

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(
                 Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
 startActivity(intent);

Comment: i gave like above in my exit onclik.but still app is there in taskmanager

Comment: This just removes the app from the recent list, not removing it from the OS cached apps.

Comment: Actually what do you mean by "remove application from task manager"? If `onDestroy()` of the activity is called , the app is closed.

Comment: `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called immediately.

Comment: after click the exit button if open taskmanager means my application name should not show in inside taskmanger list

Comment: If you followed the steps I showed, there is no way the app is still showing in your recent app. The above method worked for other people, why isn't it working for you?

Comment: hi..thease  two lines i have keep for every activity..or else only first activity

Comment: Add those two line in the `<application>` tag in Android Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

try this  to exit the application

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 

startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(startMain); 
finish();
```

Comment: thanks..i tried tis also app is closing but still is running in task manager

Comment: try this also android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Answer (score 0):

Please think really hard about if you do need to kill the application: why not let the OS figure out where and when to free the resources?

Otherwise, if you're absolutely really sure, use

finish();
As a reaction to @dave appleton's comment: First thing read the big question/answer combo @gabriel posted: Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?

- Now assuming we have that, the question here still has an answer,
  being that the code you need if you are doing anything with quitting
  is finish(). Obviously you can have more than one activity etc etc,
  but that's not the point. Lets run by some of the use-cases
- You want to let the user quit everything because of memory usage and 
  "not running in the background? Doubtfull. Let the user stop certain 
  activities in the background, but let the OS kill any unneeded
  recourses. You want a user to not go to the previous activity of your
  app? Well, either configure it so it doesn't, or you need an extra
  option. If most of the time the back=previous-activity works,
  wouldn't the user just press home if he/she wants to do something
  else? If you need some sort of reset, you can find out if/how/etc
  your application was quit, and if your activity gets focus again you 
  can take action on that, showing a fresh screen instead of restarting
  where you were. So in the end, ofcourse, finish() doesn't kill
  everthing, but it is still the tool you need I think. If there is a
  usecase for "kill all activities", I haven't found it yet

Comment: yes i have 2 activities..in 2 activities i have exit button if i click exit button in 2 activity means i have to come first activity i click exit btn in first activity menas i need close whole application

Comment: if you want to quit your one activity then just write First_activity_context_finish(); and  moveTaskToBack(true); @user2401554

Comment: noo..when i click first class exit button i need to close apllication.and remove application from task manager also

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't allow you to directly exit from the app.you just have to remove the your current activty from the stack before going to any new activity.

class first extends activity{
oncreate(){

Intent i = new Intent(getappcontext(),nextactivity);

stratactivity(i);

first.this.finish();

}

}